# Detect fake random numbers?

Tags: security, machine-learning, cryptography, probability, uuid

My client side code generates UUIDs and sends them to the server.

For example, `'6ea140caa83b485f9c98ebaacfb536ce'` would be a valid uuid4 to send back.

Is there any way to detect or prevent a user sending back a valid but "user generated" uuid4 like `'babebabebabe4abebabebabebabebabe'`?

For example, one way to prevent a certain class of these would be looking at the number of occurrences of 0's and 1's in the binary representation of the number. This could work for a string like `'00000000000040000000000000000000'` but not for all strings.

Comment: i believe you should generate your UUIDS server side, that's what we do and it's probably the safest way as you know what you generate. That being said it depend on your needs, maybe there is strong reasons why it's client-sided, but you'll need to tell us more.

Comment: Why not generate them server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little ...

there is no way to be entirely sure, but depending on the UUID version/subtype you are using there MIGHT be a way to detect at least some irregular values:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1 defines the original version 1 of UUIDs, and a layout for the uuid fields ...

you could for example check if the version and variant fields are valid...

if your UUID generation actually uses Version 1 you could, in addition to the first test of version and variant, test if the timestamp is in a valid range ... for example, it might be unlikely that the UUID in question was generated in the year 1600 ... or in the future

so tests like there could be applied to check if the value actually makes sense, or is complete gibberish ... it can not protect you against someone thinking: ok ... lets analyze this and provide a manually choosen value that satisfies all conditions

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to distinguish user generated UUID's from randomly generated UUID's.

To start with, a user generated UUID may as well be partially random. But lets assume that it is not.

In that case you want to detect a pattern. However, although you give an example of a pattern, a pattern can be almost anything. For instance, the following byte array looks completely random, right?

```
40 09 21 fb 54 44 2d 18
```

But actually it is a *nothing-up-my-sleeve number* usually used within the cryptographic community: it's simply the encoding of Pi (in this case as a 64 bit floating point, as I was somewhat lazy).

There are certainly randomness tests, for instance FIPS random number tests. Those require a very high number of input to see if something fails or succeeds. Even then: it only shows that certain statistical properties have indeed been attained by a random number generator. The encoding of Pi might very well succeed.

And annoyingly, a random number generator is perfectly possible to generate bit strings *that do not look random at all*, if just by chance. The smaller the bit string the more chance of the random number generator generating something that doesn't look random at all. And UUID's are not all that big.

So yes, of course you can do some tests, but you can never be sure: you will have both false positives as false negatives.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 makes a very good point that not all data in a UUID needs to be random. Of course it is perfectly possible to validate the non-random bits.